# How to know NavigationView is popped back in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigationview

When user taps on the back button, can we get the event and do something?

I have tried with `onDisappear` for the view, but the order of child disappearing and parent appearing is not desired. So I am looking for a way to hook to the back event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modifier `onDisappear`, I dont understand your exact case because you need the exact event of back.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false

    var destination: some View {
        Text("Detail")
                .onDisappear(perform: {
                    print("On Disappear")
                })
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: destination, isActive: $isPresented) {
                Text("Main")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the isActive and listening to the change in the binding, I know that binding does not have `didSet` but you can add it with this extension

```swift
extension Binding {
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                execute($0)
                self.wrappedValue = $0
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can add the state to monitor the state of the view

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State isPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
             NavigationLink(Text("Follow to a Text"), destination: Text("detail view"), isPresented: $isPresented.didSet{ if !self.isPresented { print("Back Pressed") } })
        }

}
```

Currently I'm unaware of any other way to do what you want without a custom button